# Issue with deploying updates to MEAN app on digital ocean

Tags: web-deployment, mean, digital-ocean, pm2

The app has been deployed and active for the last few months and have been updating it actively with more frontend updates such as design and layout in angular, I updated the app.js which is nodejs server and it has since not been able to load, I have since reverted back to previous version exactly as it was before I done anything but it doesn't seem to be working still, on Digital Ocean, I am using pm2 for app running on server. i don't get why it is acting like this.

I have also npm start too just to see if their are actual errors and back end and this is what I got:

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1043:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1271:14)
    at listen (net.js:1307:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1403:5)
    at EventEmitter.listen (/opt/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/app.js:76:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:577:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:611:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:160:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:507:3

npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-116-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.14.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! downeycrm@1.0.0 start: `node app`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the downeycrm@1.0.0 start script 'node app'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the downeycrm package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node app
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs downeycrm
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls downeycrm
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /opt/npm-debug.log
```

What does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

`Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000` means that another process is already listening on port 3000 on your host, it's probably your application that's currently running.

You can run `netstat -nltp | grep 3000` to see what process it actually is and then terminate it and restart your app.

Comment: I resolved the issue before seeing this but yes that was infact it. Appreciate the comment.